# TeamDrive resource missing capabilities field

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a list of TeamDrives in my account using V3 api. But the capabilities field is missing in the response. What am I missing?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 0):

OK I added ?fields=* to the url and it worked.